# Brownian motion program

Tags: python

So im trying to create a program that simulates brownian motion. At the moment it is not working and i cant figure out why.

I want a dynamic output where every dot begins at (0,0) after which a random coordinate is assigned to each dot so that every dot "moves" at random in the coordinate system. Now when i start the program the output is just 1 static image with dots at random positions.

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

val = input("Number of particles")
inp = int(val)

x = [0]*inp 
y = [0]*inp   

for i in range(0,inp):
    x[i] = x[i] + random.randint(0,9)
    y[i] = y[i] + random.randint(0,9)

for k in range(0,inp):  
    N=9
    plt.scatter(x[k],y[k])
    plt.hold(True)
```

Comment: Would say Brownian motion would be better modeled by starting at (0,0), picking a random vector direction, and then taking a single step in that direction to determine the ending location.  Forget about pixels; those are just rendering.  Make the algorithm work, then worry about how you'll render it.  Text output of coordinates are the way to begin.

Comment: I'm new to python and I have tried to figure out how vectors work in python but I fail to find any help. How do I work with vectors?

Comment: Vectors are math idea, independent of Python or any other computer language.  Fail to find any help?  Google brought back more hits than I could read.  Do you not have Google installed on your machine?

Comment: Im not saying i don't understand vectors what I'm saying is that I'm new to python and hence Im not familiar with the syntax...

Comment: Only one way to learn anything - get a shovel and start digging.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the updating phase (`for i in range(0, inp)`) inside a loop.

Now, you only draw each particle once; you can't get more than one image if you only run one update.

Also, you may want to use floating-point positions for the particles and update them using a randomly oriented vector of fixed modulus (with a significantly smaller modulus), otherwise you won't be able to appreciate the motion.

Maybe you can render their positions in different colours to distinguish the trajectories?